# Simulate slow burn progress

Tags: mount, burning, cd

I'm working on a "Burn Service" feature for a bigger application and find myself needing to burn a lot for testing. Problem is, mounting drives results in lightning fast burning and that's bad for testing. I'm looking for a way to mount a drive virtually that's slow to write data to. I haven't been able to find anything along those lines.

Comment: I remember DVD burners allowed to simulate. You could simulate using a real dvd burner and set write speed to x1.

Comment: That's not what I want, though. I don't have a lot of CDs and want it all done virtually.